# How do I limit to only 2 number index signature class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

After googling for a while I can't find the right answer for me.

I want to declare a class that has a number index that only allows `0` and `1` number keys.

This is what I have so far:

```
class TupleWrapperClass{
   [values:number]

   constructor(value1: number, value2: number) {
       this[0] = value1;
       this[1] = value2;
   }
}
```

The idea is that this class represents a numeric tuple `[number,number]` and can only store 2 numbers.
The problem I have is that it allows adding more than 2 elements:

```
let t = new TupleWrapperClass(0,3);
console.log(t[0]); // Output: 0
console.log(t[1]); // Output: 3
console.log(t[2]); // Output: undefined
t[2] = 7
console.log(t[2]); // Output: 7
```

I've read some answers where they define a type and the indexer, this seems to work

```
type Index = 0 | 1
type TupleWrapperType = { [k in Index]?: number }
```

BUT, I can't do a type check:

```
let t: TuppleWrapperType = { 0: 2, 1: 5 };
if(typeof t === TuppleWrapperType){} // Fails.
```

I've read a lot about custom types and why we can't check their type at runetime, that's why I switched to creating a custom class, since that do let me do a type check:

```
let t = new TupleWrapperClass(0,3);
if(t instanceof TuppleWrapperClass){} // All good
```

How do I limit my TuppleWrapperClass to only 2 indexes?

Comment: For my own curiosity's sake, why not just _use_ `[number, number]` since that is a numeric tuple?  You can even create a type alias: `type Tuple2<A, B> = [A, B]` and then use it wherever you need such a thing:  `const twoNumbers: Tuple2<number, number> = [1, 3];`.  The type test is also simple: `function isTuple2<A, B>(value: any): value is Tuple2<A, B> { return Array.isArray(value) && value.length === 2; }`

Comment: I'm not well versed in JS and TS. The problem with [number, number] is that I need to differentiate an `any` param between an array and a tuple. Since in JS a tuple is an array, I can't do a simple type check.
I'll try what you propose, is there any benefit going either way?

Comment: Yeah your "isTuple" function won't work in my use case, an array would be recognized as a tuple, and in my use case they need to be treated as separated types. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one, declare the type in class before instantiation

```
class TupleWrapperClass{
   0: number;
   1: number;
   constructor(value1: number, value2: number) {
       this[0] = value1;
       this[1] = value2;
   }
}

let t = new TupleWrapperClass(0,3);

console.log(t[0]); // OK
console.log(t[1]); // OK
console.log(t[2]); // Type Error
```

Comment: Holly molly, is that it? I'll test this right away and come back, thanks!